# How would you create a terminal alias to watch the latest log file update in real time?

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, pipe, zsh

Situation: I want a one line command that can pull out the latest log (updates hourly), and watch as it changes. Here's an attempt that might explain less obscurely:

```
tail -500f $(ls | grep PackageName | sort | tail -1)
```

The above approach works actually, however when I create an alias for it, it doesn't update the $(~~~) value. Can anyone suggest a reason for it?

So, another attempt (the point of this question):

```
ls | grep PackageName | sort | tail -1 | tail -500f (LogFileNameTimeStampLatest)
```

Turns out it just outputs the result from last pipe (LogFileNameTimeStampLatest). And it makes sense as well, because that's what the 2nd last pipe command (`tail -1` was doing in the first place)

I wanted to understand how would one use the output from last pipe to point to a file in the next pipe (and not just the LogFileName). Concretely, how would one use an output of one pipe as an argument for another pipe?

Comment: When you defined the alias, did you enclose it in single-quotes or double-quotes? You want single-quotes; double-quotes would give the result you describe. But functions are generally better than aliases (see @tripleee's answer).

Comment: What are some trade-offs to using an alias?

Comment: Aliases are ok for really simple shortcuts (e.g. `alias ll='ls -l'`), but for anything nontrivial a function is the way to go. See [this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163882/alias-vs-function-in-bash-scripts) for more discussion and differences.

Answer (score 3):

Don't create an alias. Create a function.

```
watchlog () {
    tail -500f "$(ls *PackageName* | sort | tail -1)"
}
```

The double quotes are necessary if the output contains file names which themselves contain shell metacharacters, including any spaces.

There are probably good ways to avoid the [use of `ls` in a script](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) but the trivial solution is to just not attempt to put this in an alias.

The same command could be rephrased with `xargs` which I guess is what you are trying to ask last:

```
ls *PackageName* | sort | tail -1 |
xargs tail -500f
```

Comment: Hi! I followed your advice to create a function as you suggested. However, the command doesn't update itself for logs forming in the subsequent hours. I can't figure out which param or arg I'm not doing right.

Comment: And thanks for the `xargs` tip! Currently my method looks like: 
`eplog() {
    tail -500f "$(cd /deploy/var/env/SummerEndWebsite/output/logs/ && find SummerEndWebsite* | sort | tail -1)"
}`

Comment: The `cd` looks weird, won't it stop working if you run it in the wrong directory? Better to do `find /deploy/var/env/etc -maxdepth 1 -name 'SummerEndWebsite*' | sort | tail -n 1`

Comment: 'cd' looks weird I know, I just wanted to be able to `cd` into that directory as well, so I chose to write it that way. One could use `find` like you mentioned and get away with never needing `cd`. Also, `cd` gets an absolute path so I'm not really sure how changing directory would affect it's behaviour.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, the output from `find` will refer to a different directory than the one where the outer `tail` runs so you will get "file not found".

Comment: Wouldn't the change-directory from the inner `cd` affect the directory path of the outer `tail`. Seems like I made this implicit assumption - that the outer `find` recognizes that the `cd` changed directory in the inside.

Comment: And that it wasn't the right assumption to make.

Comment: No, a subprocess cannot affect its parent.